# Json.Net Serialization programmatically

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have to serialize into json some informations and then write them to a file.
Actually the result i want to achieve is this:

```
{
  "Email": "james@example.com",
  "Active": true,
  "CreatedDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is the class i use to store info:

```
public class JSON
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string[] libraries { get; set; }
}
```

and then i use this to serialize them:

```
JSON account = new JSON
{
    Email = "james@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    libraries = new[] {"Small","Medium","Large" }

};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
```

the problem is that actually the result i have is this:

```
{
  "Email": "james@example.com",
  "Active": true,
  "CreatedDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z",
  "libraries": [
    "Small",
    "Medium",
    "Large"
  ]
}
```

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your JSON class to this one:

```
public class Library
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class JSON
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<Library> libraries { get; set; }
}
```

**How to generate classes with online tool**

The good hint is to use [JSON to C# converter](http://json2csharp.com/) which will generate you C# classes.

**How to generate classes with Visual Studio**

Other option is to use built in Visual Studio feature (works in VS2013 and above).

If you have your JSON file in the clipboard you can go:

Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON as Classes

**How to use new class**

```
JSON account = new JSON
{
    Email = "james@example.com",
    Active = true,
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    libraries = new List<Library>  
            {
              new Library {name = "Small"},
              new Library {name = "Medium"},
              new Library {name = "Large"} 
            }

};
```

Comment: and what do i do with this? libraries = new[] {"Small","Medium","Large" }

Comment: it works fine if i use public Library[] libraries { get; set; } instead of public List<Library> libraries { get; set; }. With that it give me a conversion error

Comment: Yep, you're right. I updated the example one more time. You either use array or a List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom converter:

```
public class ArrayItemAsObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string[]);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string[] items = (string[])value;

        writer.WriteStartArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("name");
            writer.WriteValue(items[i]);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
///

[JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayItemAsObjectConverter))]
public string[] libraries { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio, you can create the classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Library[] libraries { get; set; }
}

  public class Library
  {
      public string name { get; set; }
  }
```

You need copy the json string and paste special as json class. Go to the menu then click **EDIT** and you will find it.

And

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

JavaScriptSerializer oJS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootObject oRootObject = new RootObject();
oRootObject = oJS.Deserialize<RootObject>(Your JSon String);
```